# Ruby i/o performance - reading file char by char

Tags: ruby, performance, io

**Short version:**
how to read from STDIN (or a file) char by char while maintaining high performance using Ruby? (though the problem is probably not Ruby specific)

**Long version:**
While learning Ruby I'm designing a little utility that has to read from a piped text data, find and collect numbers in it and do some processing.

```
cat huge_text_file.txt | program.rb

input  > 123123sdas234sdsd5a ...
output > 123123, 234, 5, ...
```

The text input might be huge (gigabytes) and it might not contain newlines or whitespace (any non-digit char is a separator) so I did a char by char reading (though I had my concerns about the performance) and it turns out doing it this way is incredibly slow.

Simply reading char by char with no processing on a 900Kb input file takes around 7 seconds!

```
while c = STDIN.read(1)
end
```

If I input data with newlines and read line by line, same file is read 100x times faster.

```
while s = STDIN.gets
end
```

It seems like reading from a pipe with `STDIN.read(1)` doesn't involve any buffering and every time read happens, hard drive is hit - but shouldn't it be cached by OS?

Doesn't `STDIN.gets` read char by char internally until it encounters '`\n`'?

Using C, I would probably read data in chunks though I would I have to deal with numbers being split by buffer window but that doesn't look like an elegant solution for Ruby. So what is the proper way of doing this?

**P.S Timing reading the same file in Python:**

```
for line in f:
    line
f.close()
```

Running time is 0.01 sec.

```
c = f.read(1)
while c:
    c = f.read(1)
f.close()
```

Running time is 0.17 sec.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the problem here isn’t so much the IO but the garbage collector. Using `read(1)` will create a new String object for each byte of the file. You might get better results if you create a temp string and reuse it with each call to `read`. So if you first do `buffer = ""`, then you can call read in your loop as `STDIN.read(1, buffer)`.

Comment: @matt thanks for the suggestion! I tried that, it is marginally faster. On a 900K file piped from `cat` I get averaged running time for `STDIN.read(1)` - 4.6 sec, for `buffer=''; STDIN.read(1,buffer)` - 4.5 sec, for `STDIN.gets` - 0.08 sec. I also tried moving everything from SSD to HDD to see if that matters - it doesn't. I think input file must be cached by OS and hard drive is not really hit every read.

Comment: I timed the same stuff in Python, running time for `for line in file: line` is 0.01 sec, for `while c: c=file.read(1)` it's 0.17 sec. It is still more than 10 times faster to read in chunks though.

Comment: Try using [`each_byte`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/IO.html#method-i-each_byte) instead of the `while` loop: `STDIN.each_byte do |b| ... end`. That seems much faster, but I don’t really know why.

Comment: (or `each_char` depending on your data–you‘ll need to take into account encoding).

Comment: @matt Thank you very much, it is indeed 10 times faster than `read(1)`! If you post it like an answer, I'll accept it. I ended up using reading by chunks (and dealing with splitted numbers) anyway because with a big buffer it seems to be the fastest way.

Answer (score 4):

This script reads the IO object word by word, and executes the block every time 1000 words have been found or the end of the file has been reached.

No more than 1000 words will be kept in memory at the same time. Note that using `" "` as separator means that "words" might contain newlines.

This scripts uses [`IO#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/IO.html#method-i-each) to specify a separator (a whitespace in this case, to get an [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerator.html) of words), [`lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to avoid doing any operation on the whole file content and [`each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to get an array of batch_size words.

```
batch_size = 1000

STDIN.each(" ").lazy.each_slice(batch_size) do |batch|
  # batch is an Array of batch_size words
end
```

Instead of using cat and `|`, you could also read the file directly :

```
batch_size = 1000

File.open('huge_text_file.txt').each(" ").lazy.each_slice(batch_size) do |batch|
  # batch is an Array of batch_size words
end
```

With this code, no number will be split, no logic is needed, it should be much faster than reading the file char by char and it will use much less memory than reading the whole file into a String.

Comment: Thanks! It is faster but in effect it is almost the same as `gets` but using whitespace instead of `\n` as a separator. In this problem a separator is anything but a digit and a string between occasional whitespace or newline can be huge so we might get out of memory fast. Is there a way to somehow automagically regexp through the text without reading it all? :) How does `.each(" ")` or `.gets` do it? Do the read a block, split and then discard a part after separator?
P.S. Pipe is used for flexibility so I can chain commands or get input from `curl`.

Comment: Then you'll have to read in fixed length chunks, and see if you split a number.

Comment: Seems that way.. by the way using `each("\n").each_slice(batch_size)`  is indeed a little bit faster than `f.each_line` but half as slow as using `.gets`. I guess it's because intermediate objects are created.